# How can i properly resize my images for further processing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

I want to resize my images( to a smaller size) :

How can I resize my images properly without the bad pixels effect for further cnn processing afterward.

Comment: Try adding the keyword argument `interpolation=INTER_AREA` to your `cv2.resize` calls.

Comment: I appreciate the advice but rather than testing every possible suggestion that may come up, the image is there, and the code as well it would be helpful if you could test on it and add in answers in case of success, thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you don't give any reasonable metrics of what you define as bad - nobody except you can decide if one or another interpolation method suits you, therefore please check the suggested interpolation type and if it suits you - notify the responder.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. my question explicitly mentions that the expected result is "The resized images should not be skewed or deformed" anything other than that is bad.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems are due to interpolation artifacts. As you can check in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#cv2.resize) for `cv2.resize`, by default `BILINEAR` is used. You should probably go with their suggestion and try using the `INTER_AREA` version. You may also want to check other options and see which one suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at [vector images here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) at Wikipedia if you really want a clear picture in a small size. OpenCV library doesn't provide a function for converting bitmap images to vector images.